Gambler ruin's: Probability of k consecutive win before j consecutive loss
Assume that a stock has a probability of $p$ to win, a probability of $q$ to lose, and a probability of $(1-p-q)$ to remain every day. What is the probability of $k$ consecutive wins occur before $j$ consecutive loses?
I am trying come up with a martingale to solve it. Denote $\tau:\min\{t > 0: X_{t} \text{ contains $k$ consecutive wins or $j$ consecutive loss}\},$ where $X_{t}$ is the total money at the time $t.$ I am stuck on how to construct this martingale. Any hints would be helpful!

Are the $k+j$ consecutive days the first $k+j$ days? If you hold the stock "forever," the probability that the event "$k$ wins followed by $j$ losses" occurs sometime equals $1$.  If you refer to the first $k+j$ days, though, that's just $p^kq^j$, no martingale needed.  If you randomly choose $k+j$ points, it's the same as if you chose the first $k+j$ points.

In short, the problem is what is the probability of k consecutive wins occurs before j consecutive loses? Thanks for your help!

Note that such a calculation assumes the absence of momentum/reversal effects in stock returns.

@ZhihaoXu IIUC then I'm almost certain this would be $\frac{p^k}{p^k + q^j}$ but I haven't worked out the full explanation as to why so I won't make this an answer

@ischmidt20 Can you give me a hint about how to get this answer?

If $k = j = 1$ then the question becomes "what is the probability the stock wins given that it either wins or loses?" and the answer is definitely $\frac{p}{p+q}$. If $k = j$ and $k > 1$ then the question is "what is the probability the next $k$ days are all wins given that they are either all wins or all losses (which happens w.p. $p^k + q^k$)? Where I get shaky is the case where $k \neq j$ (which is why I only leave this as a comment)
